# data caching in mysql

Tags: mysql, caching

can we cache queries in mysql with php.
or please suggest me some ways to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq : As long as your question is detailed and specific, written clearly and simply, and of interest to other programmers, it is welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has it's own internal [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html).  You could set up your own system using [shared memory](http://www.php.net/shmop), [memcached](http://memcached.org), simple text files, et al, but MySQL's pretty good at handling it without any extras.